# Почему создается дополнительное поле Section_Id, EF, Code first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvc, codefirst

### Создаю класс Section

```
public class Section
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ChiefId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Chief { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

### Есть стандартный класс ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int? SectionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SectionId")] <<<<<<<<<< добавлено, но не помогает
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }


    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Обратите внимание, что authenticationType должен совпадать с типом, определенным в CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Здесь добавьте утверждения пользователя
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

### Добавляю контекст

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    * * *
```

> Почему в БД создается дополнительное поле Section_Id с нулевым значением (на рисунке показано создание ключа - закомментированное значение)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> А при удалении его из БД бросается исключение в контроллере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> И есть ли способ избавиться от этого дополнительного поля?

Comment: А как вы, интересно, собираетесь хранить тогда ссылку на Section, если не по Id?

Comment: Т.е. у вас создаётся и SectionId и Section_Id? Или что-то из этого вы создали руками самостоятельно?

Comment: Немного не так. SectionId я создаю явно в классе ApplicationUser. А поле Section_Id создается неявно фреймворком в самой базе при миграции. Когда я его пытаюсь удалить - выбрасывается исключение. Не могу понять почему оно создается..

Comment: Почему-то EF не понял что вы имеете ввиду, попробуйте указать внешний ключ явно с помощью атрибута (ForeignKey вроде, надо пометить им навигационное свойство: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/6.3.php)

Comment: не помогло.. поле по прежнему там и при удалении ошибка.. изменил код вопроса согласно исправлению.

Comment: Показывайте новый код

Comment: Потому что у вас между таблицами две параллельные связи, а не одна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Entity framework для того чтобы создать связь "один ко многим" необходимо описать ее в каждом классе, между которыми создается эта связь.
В одном классе (один) - это наличие двух полей - обычного и навигационного. (см. код ниже)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    *  *  *
    public int? SectionId { get; set; }
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }
    *  *  *
```

а другой класс (многие) должен также содержать реализацию этой связи - коллекцию

```
public class Section
{
    *  *  *
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Staff { get; set; }
}
```

---

В вопросе описана одна такая связь (SectionId,Section => Staff), в то время как вторая не реализована до конца.
Наличие с одной стороны пары свойств

```
public class Section
{
    *  *  *
    public string ChiefId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Chief { get; set; }
    *  *  *
```

требует реализации коллекции в классе ApplicationUser, например:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    *  *  *
    public ICollection<Section> Sections { get; set; }
    *  *  *
```